# With the Yoast SEO plugin, is it possible to make the meta description a required form field?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am referring to the meta description field as pictured below:

[image: Yoast screen shot]

Is it possible to configure the plugin so as to make that field required? If a user tries to publish a post with it empty, they would be prompted to fill it in.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to avoid empty meta description field is to set a default meta description using meta template variables in the dashboard.

This article in the Yoast knowledge base explains how to do this and lists the available variables:

- https://kb.yoast.com/kb/yoast-wordpress-seo-titles-metas-template-variables/

Here's what I ended up doing:

- Login as admin.
- In dashboard: SEO >Titles and Metas > Post Types
- In the `Meta description template` field for Posts and Pages, I entered the following value and pressed **Save Changes** button:

  ```
  %%sitename%% : %%title%% (%%date%%)
  ```

Here's the tag it produced:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="My Blog : A New Post Awakens (August 16, 2017)" />
```